# Android INJECT_EVENTS permission on a rooted devce

Tags: android, permissions

I am trying to create a tv box application that will have a service running in the background and receive signals from remote app.Tv box app and remote app communicate to each other through TCP. that will be capable of injecting events into whatever activity is running. But I am not able to inject events into an Activity that is not part of my application by calling Intent. Like open wifi setting and select desired wifi. However if I try to do this without an activity from my application running I get a permission error saying that I don't have the INJECT_EVENTS permission. I've added this permission to my manifest like this:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"></uses-permission>`

It is still throwing the same permission exception though. After a bit of searching I've gotten the answer that in order to receive the INJECT_EVENTS permission your app must be signed by the same signature that the system is signed with. I am unclear however what exactly this means. Is there a way I can achieve this keeping in mid that I do not have access to the same signature.

Answer (score 0):

> It is still throwing the same permission exception though. After a bit of searching I've gotten the answer that in order to receive the INJECT_EVENTS permission your app must be signed by the same signature that the system is signed with. I am unclear however what exactly this means. Is there a way I can achieve this keeping in mid that I do not have access to the same signature.

**Install your app in `/system/app`**

> [As you've said you will grant root access from the user for your app]

*And, an app running as root doesn't need any normal Android android permission as it has already been granted the highest-level of permission available*

**1**. First, get the location of the apk where it's located in the system and put it to sdcard.

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> apps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo info : apps) {

    File fx = new File(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);

    if(fx.getName().toString().contains(getApplicationContext().getPackageName())){

    File fz = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());   
    fz.mkdirs();            
    fz = new File(fz.getPath()+"/"+getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".apk");
    fz.createNewFile();

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fx);

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fz);

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
  }
}
```

**2**. Execute the following commands to remount the /system directory as read/write and to install the application into the /system/app directory from the SDCARD where system:

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("su -c mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system");

String x = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("su -c cp /sdcard/"+x+".apk /system/app");

Runtime.getRuntime.exec("su -c reboot");
```

Now, try to execute your codes and give a comment.

Comment: Thank for reply I have make system application using ES File Explorer apk and  watching this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lUCLnBXAFo&t=239s
It is still throwing the same permission exception.